# Generate div box based on database rows

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to generate div box dynamically based on database row. For example, if sql query retrieves 3 ids then 3 div box should appear one after another. I'm not getting logic to implement this.

I'll appreciate your any reply....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Repeater** control, which can be customized entirely and  you can databind it to an SqlDataSource control.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="FooSqlDataSource">
    <HeaderTemplate><!-- header content --></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div><!-- content --></div>
    </ItemTemplate>            
    <SeparatorTemplate><!-- separating content --></SeparatorTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate><!-- alternatig content --></AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate><!-- footer content --></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: edited your answer as the `<div>` without the `<ItemTemplate>` wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, I have to use repeater control. Actually, I'm implementing chatting app like gmail & facebook, so if user click online user then chat box should appear for each click. Could you suggest me now how to achieve this...?